# Is there way to achieve inside the table header having a three table data?

Tags: html, html-table

I have a problem to achieve a table header which in some parts contains a second row of header elements, where three `th` cells belong to one main header cell above them. I don't know if is it possible to create an html table like this. To what I mean, I am providing my sample code and an illustration.

**Goal:**

[image: my goal]

Please take a look the hyphen line, that table i want to achieve to my table on my html. so right now i have the output of this. please see the second illustration.

[image: my html table]

**Here is my html code:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">

  <thead>
    <tr style="font-size:13px; text-align: center;">
      <th>1600</th>
      <th colspan="2">P1W1</th>
      <th colspan="2">TGT</th>
      <th colspan="2">LY</th>
      <th colspan="3" scope="colgroup">Variance Vs Target</th>
      <th colspan="3" scope="colgroup">Variance Vs 2018</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="font-size:12px;">

      <td style="">ADS</td>

      <td style="text-align: right;">23,635</td>
      <td></td>

      <td style="text-align: right;">21,676</td>
      <td></td>

      <td style="text-align: right;">20,790</td>
      <td></td>

      <td style="text-align: right;">1,959</td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">9.0%</td>
      <td></td>

      <td style="text-align: right;">2,845</td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">13.7%</td>
      <td></td>

    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rowspan="2"` on all `tr` elements which *don't *  have a second-level header and create a second row of `tr` elements that only contains the second-level `th` elements:

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

.header_2nd_level>th {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: grey;
}
th, td {
border: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">

  <thead>
    <tr style="font-size:13px; text-align: center;">
      <th rowspan="2">1600</th>
      <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">P1W1</th>
      <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">TGT</th>
      <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">LY</th>
      <th colspan="3" scope="colgroup">Variance Vs Target</th>
      <th colspan="3" scope="colgroup">Variance Vs 2018</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="header_2nd_level">
      <th>amount</th>
      <th>%</th>
      <th>ppt</th>
      <th>amount</th>
      <th>%</th>
      <th>ppt</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="font-size:12px;">

      <td style="">ADS</td>

      <td style="text-align: right;">23,635</td>
      <td></td>

      <td style="text-align: right;">21,676</td>
      <td></td>

      <td style="text-align: right;">20,790</td>
      <td></td>

      <td style="text-align: right;">1,959</td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">9.0%</td>
      <td></td>

      <td style="text-align: right;">2,845</td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">13.7%</td>
      <td></td>

    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Johanned hi, why the first to fourth table header goes down..?

Comment: @SoulAiker As I wrote in the answer: Because these `th` cells have `rowspan="2" `

Comment: ok now, i use style="vertical-align:middle"; thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This could work:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">

    <thead>
      <tr style="font-size:13px; text-align: center;">
        <th rowspan="2">1600</th>
        <th rowspan="2" >P1W1</th>
        <th rowspan="2" >TGT</th rowspan="2">
        <th rowspan="2" >LY</th rowspan="2">
        <th colspan="3" scope="colgroup">Variance Vs Target</th>
        <th colspan="3" scope="colgroup">Variance Vs 2018</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>%</th>
          <th>ppt</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>%</th>
          <th>ppt</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr style="font-size:12px;">

        <td style="text-align: right;">ADS</td>

        <td style="text-align: right;">23,635</td>

        <td style="text-align: right;">21,676</td>

        <td style="text-align: right;">20,790</td>

        <td style="text-align: right;">1,959</td>
        <td style="text-align: right;">9.0%</td>
        <td></td>

        <td style="text-align: right;">2,845</td>
        <td style="text-align: right;">13.7%</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try making use of `rowspan` and `columnspan` property correctly.

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr style="font-size:13px; text-align: center;">
      <th colspan="1" rowspan="2">1600</th>
      <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">P1W1</th>
      <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">TGT</th>
      <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">LY</th>
      <th colspan="3" rowspan="1" scope="colgroup1">Variance Vs Target</th>
      <th colspan="3" rowspan="1" scope="colgroup2">Variance Vs 2018</th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="font-size:13px; text-align: center;">
        <td>Amount</td>
        <td>%</td>
        <td>ppt</td>

        <td>Amount</td>
        <td>%</td>
        <td>ppt</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="font-size:12px;">
      <td style="">ADS</td>

      <td style="text-align: right;">23,635</td>
      <td></td>

      <td style="text-align: right;">21,676</td>
      <td></td>

      <td style="text-align: right;">20,790</td>
      <td></td>

      <td style="text-align: right;">1,959</td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">9.0%</td>
      <td></td>

      <td style="text-align: right;">2,845</td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">13.7%</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```